# Kubernetes deployment status ImagePullBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, docker-registry

when I’m trying to pull a docker image, it throws this error ImagePullBackOff

```
NAME                                   READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
mynodeappdeployment-77b96f978f-zz9kh   0/1     ErrImagePull       0          8s
mynodeappdeployment-7c459c57b4-dj7c6   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          4m12s
mynodeappdeployment-7c459c57b4-gzxms   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          4m12s
mynodeappdeployment-7c459c57b4-p9ghl   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          4m12s
```

My docker image is @ https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/narasingu/node-docker

My deployment yaml configuration is

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: nodejs-server-service
spec:
    selector:
        app: nodejs-server-app
    ports:
    -   protocol: "TCP"
        port: 8080
        targetPort: 80
        nodePort: 32000
    type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: mynodeappdeployment
spec:
    replicas: 3
    selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: nodejs-server-app
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: nodejs-server-app
        spec:
            containers:
            - name: myapp
              image: narasingu/node-docker:v1
              ports:
              - containerPort: 9000
---
```

Looks like it's not pulling the docker image, any help?

Comment: is that a private image or public ?

Comment: it is public i guess , here is the image
https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/narasingu/node-docker/tags?page=1

Comment: where is the k8s cluster? Does any other image works? Does the k8s nodes have access to internet?

Comment: Yes, was able to retrieve other namespaces, was able to do a docker pull manually

Comment: you tried docker pull from the kubernetes node? it worked on my cluster

Comment: How do I do it? I am logged with minikube start and have created the deployment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217476/discussion-between-arghya-sadhu-and-sai-prakash-narasingu).

Comment: Sure, In the chat

Comment: Run `minikube ssh` and then `docker pull narasingu/node-docker:v1` and let me know it it pulls it or maybe fails with some error.

Comment: Throws error Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.4:45132->192.168.64.1:53: i/o timeout

Comment: It looks like you have issue with dns (port 53 is dns). Try changeing minikube's dns in `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Or try adding following line to this file: `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and then try pulling it again.

Comment: Tried, but this too did not work, am able to pull docker images from the hub, and run it, but it does not work through kubectl @HelloWorld

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu, Do you have other insights?